# What is the right approach for serializing/deserializing data in a culture-insensitive manner?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, cultureinfo

I need to persist data to xml and then read it back in a way that data serialized in one culture will then be parse-able in another.

As I see it there are two ways to accomplish this.  I can either make sure that all parse/tostring/etc. methods are using the invariant culture, or I could set the thread's culture to invariant, do all my (de)serializing, and then switch it back to whatever it was before.

I know that the first approach is deemed to be the right one, but switching the thread's culture seems to be easier and less bug-prone.  Is there a reason for why the first approach is preferred?  Is there some other approach that I am perhaps not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `WriteValue` methods of the [`XmlWriter` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx), and the `ReadContentAs` methods of the [`XmlReader` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx).

You can also use the methods of the [`XmlConvert` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx).

All of these methods produce XML-standard formats, which are culture-independent.

Comment: I'm aware, but for reasons that are beside the point here, there are places where I have to do the string conversions manually.  Also, even if various serialization helpers do this for me, I want to understand the correct practices myself.